# Don't have right output while comparing chars

Tags: c, struct, char, compare, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct patients{
char last_name[15];
int passport_number;
char disease[30];
char doctors_last_name[15];
};

int main (){
int n,i;
char enter_doctors_last_name [15];



struct patients mas_struct[3]={{"Ivanov",5457401,"COVID-18","Davis"},{"Petrov",2864228,"COVID-19","Davis"},{"Petrova",63863380,"COVID-19","Dixon"}};
    printf("\nPatients:");
    printf("\n Last name  |   Passport number  | \tDisease   |   Doctor's last name ");
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("\n %s \t%d \t%s \t%s",mas_struct[i].last_name,mas_struct[i].passport_number,mas_struct[i].disease,mas_struct[i].doctors_last_name);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nEnter doctor's last name:");
    scanf("%s", enter_doctors_last_name);
    printf("\nPatients:");

for (i=0;i<3;i++)
 if(mas_struct[i].doctors_last_name == enter_doctors_last_name)
    printf("\n %s \t%d \t%s \t%s",mas_struct[i].last_name,mas_struct[i].passport_number,mas_struct[i].disease,mas_struct[i].doctors_last_name);

return 0;
}
```

Got trouble in comparing chars, it doesn't work and I can't come up with the right words for googling it.

In the last lines when **I type "Davis" or "Dixon"** for *enter_doctors_last_name*

**Output is just Patients**

I also tried to use *gets* function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare strings with `==` operator, use `strcmp` instead:

```
if (!strcmp(mas_struct[i].doctors_last_name,enter_doctors_last_name)){/*...*/}
```

`scanf` with `"%s"` specifier is very unsafe use `"%14s"` instead, the -1 character is to reserve space for the null-terminator.

If you need names with more than 1 word you should use `"%14[^\n]"`, reads everything until the newline character is found.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot about this function and feel like an idiot right now

Comment: @morep219, you're welcome, no need for that, these things happen.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `strcmp()` function for comparing strings.